# Display trailing zeros in ticks

Tags: plotting

When I specify tick marks in ArrayPlot I want to keep the number of trailing zero's that I specify. One work around is to use a label for that tick mark (i.e. Ticks->{0.8,0.9,{1.0,"1.0"},1.1,1.2}), but is there a neater solution to save me doing this manually?

For example if I generate a plot with the code

```
legend = {0.9996 + 0.0001 #, 0.9996 + 0.0001 #} & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
ArrayPlot[legend, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
 DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.9996, 1.0004}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{0.9996, 0.9997, 0.9998, 0.9999, 1.0000, 1.0001, 
    1.0002, 1.0003, 1.0004}, None}, AspectRatio -> 7, 
 LabelStyle -> Large]
```

which gives me

[image]

we see the "1." looks out of place as it is.

Comment: There are a number of ways to set how a number is displayed: `NumberForm`, `PaddedForm`, `SetPrecision`.  You could `Map` one of these over your ticks: `{#, NumberForm[#, {5, 4}]}&/@ ticks`.

Comment: @wxffles You seem to have beat me too it. :(

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(22722)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22722/121) or [(33297)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33297/121).

Comment: Related: [(3436)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3436/121),
[(5276)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5276/121),
[(5369)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/121),
[(8791)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8791/121),
[(8923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8923/121),
[(23763)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23763/121),
[(39247)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39247/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a function with `NumberForm` to construct your `FrameTicks`.

```
FrameTicks -> {{#, NumberForm[#, {5, 4}]} & /@ legend[[All, 1]], None}
```